# What is the whole command to run Slither by terminal?

Tags: slither

What is the whole and correct Slither command to analyze a smart contract. According to the Slither guide ([here](https://github.com/crytic/slither)) I tried this:

```
slither path/contract.sol
```

But this is the result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ethsec/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/slither/__main__.py", line 744, in main_impl
    ) = process_all(filename, args, detector_classes, printer_classes)
  File "/home/ethsec/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/slither/__main__.py", line 76, in process_all
    compilations = compile_all(target, **vars(args))
  File "/home/ethsec/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/crytic_compile/crytic_compile.py", line 660, in compile_all
    raise ValueError(f"Unresolved target: {str(target)}")
ValueError: Unresolved target: F:/ImnCrypt/Implementation/Develop/PublicKey.sol
```

I think it needs a correct and resolved target that I don't know what it is. What command I should try?

Comment: Solved or need help??

Comment: @SolidityLearner Solved, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should try

```
slither .
```

in the project file.
Slither usually find its way

Comment: If my project is a Truffle project, do I try it in the contract folder or the Truffle project folder?